# chatbot no whatsapp

Tags: json

estou criando umchatbot no wtsapp para ele retornar os elementos de um array...só que preciso de umaquebra de linha... já tentei o \n nada. ele retorna em mensagens diferentes..gostaria de ter q quebra de linha na mesma mensagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quero que esses dois itens: saiam na mesma mensagem e não separadas como acima.

segue o código:

```
for (let i = 0; i < itemkeys.length; i++) {  
  let item = peditems[itemkeys[i]];
 
  if (item.box_type1 == 'Risoto de Galinhada') {
    precounit = 20;
  } else if (item.box_type1 == 'Carreteiro') {
    precounit = 20;
  } else if (item.box_type1 == 'Caipira') {
    precounit = 18;
  } else if (item.box_type1 == 'Baião de Dois') {
    precounit = 17;
  } else if (item.box_type1 == 'Risoto de Filé Mignon') {
    precounit = 25;
  } else if (item.box_type1 == 'Risoto de Frango e Bacon') {
    precounit = 20;
  }  else if (item.box_type1 == 'Risoto de Camarão') {
    precounit = 30;
  }  else if (item.box_type1 == 'Risoto de Galinhada') {
    precounit = 20;
  }  else if (item.box_type1 == 'Shitake e Gorgonzola') {
    precounit = 28;
  }  else if (item.box_type1 == 'Shitake Vegano') {
    precounit = 25;
  }

  subtotal = precounit*item.number;
  agent.add(` ${item.number} ${item.box_type1}` + ' - R$ ' + subtotal.toFixed(2));
  contador = contador + 1;
  var subtotarray = [];
  var adiciona = subtotarray.push(subtotal);
  for(var t = 0; t < subtotarray.length; t++){
    total = total + subtotarray[t];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema, resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    self.caixa_de_mensagem.send_keys("Digite algum número")
    self.caixa_de_mensagem.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
    self.caixa_de_mensagem.send_keys("1- Para fazer uma compra")
    self.caixa_de_mensagem.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
    self.caixa_de_mensagem.send_keys("2- Formas de pagamento")
    self.caixa_de_mensagem.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
    self.caixa_de_mensagem.send_keys("3- Nossas filiais")
```